# Can't pause audio during applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, nstimer, appdelegate

I can't change the values or alter any variables or objects declared. Can anyone see what's wrong?

In my app delegate method.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    MainPage *mp = [[MainPage alloc]init];

    mp.newTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:mp.date];
    [mp.timer invalidate];
    mp.switchT = 1;
    mp.playBarButton.enabled = YES;
    mp.pauseBarButton.enabled = NO;
    mp.stopBarButton.enabled = YES;
   [mp.avPlayer pause];

}
```

None of these actions above are executed. In my `mainpage.h` file I have the followed declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer;
@property (strong, retain) NSTimer *timer;
@property (strong, retain) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval newTime;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger switchT;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *playBarButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *pauseBarButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *stopBarButton;
```

Of course in my implementation file these are synthesized and all works well with my code within `mainpage.m` just not in my appDelegate file. Can anyone see the problem? Note this is a fully functioning app everything works well just can't execute the following code in my applicationDidEnterBackground method and I'm assuming it's the way my properties are made? Also no errors with my code written in the app delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(goBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil]; // and later
 - (void) goBackground { [timer invalidate], timer = nil; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This `MainPage *mp = [[MainPage alloc]init];` create a **new** `MainPage` object.  Changing values in one object is not going to affect the display of a different `MainPage` object.

Either give your app delegate a reference to the object you're actually displaying or put a handler for a background notification inside `MainPage` so that it can do its own work.

Comment: Valid point but even if I do something like this [mp.self pause:nil]; which is the my pause method it'll trigger that method but the actions within wont get performed and just return, nil, null, nan etc. Could you show me with my code provided what you mean. Thanks. Im really stumped with this one.

Comment: That makes sense because you've created a valid object, so its methods and variables exist.  To show you how to fix what you have, I'd have to know how and where your existing `MainPage` is created. Or, as I said: "put a handler for a background notification inside MainPage".  The docs for `applicationDidEnterBackground` should give the name of the matching notification.

Comment: Thank you. I found it. This is how i did it[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(goBackground)
    name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
    object:nil];

// and later:
- (void) goBackground {
    [timer invalidate], timer = nil;
}